# ADB and Fastboot displays different devices

Tags: adb, fastboot

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader of my device, Cherry Mobile Fuze, which is a port of Micromax A96.

As seen on the screenshot, is it normal that the ADB displays a device that is different from the device being displayed by fastboot?

[image: ADB and Fastboot displays different devices]

Comment: That's nothing unusual. Most devices use different IDs in normal/fastboot/recovery mode to indicate the *mode* they're in. Try `lsusb` in each mode, and you will see the corresponding data: manufacturer_id will be the same in all 3 modes, but the device_id part will differ.

Comment: Anytime. I guess I should have made that an answer: AFAIK it's a general rule, though I cannot speak for all devices of course. I will post it as answer now, so you can "accept" it (tick the check-mark next to it) – and other visitors can see this is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Fastboot, (recovery) and your "normal Android" are different systems, each using their own configuration and "device serial".

### TL;DR

That's nothing unusual. Most devices<sup>1</sup> use different IDs in normal/[fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot)/[recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) to indicate the mode they're in. You can cross-check that with the `lsusb` command on your Linux shell prompt, which reflects this by different device IDs. On top of that, some devices even use different IDs depending on what "normal mode" you've activated. To give an example, here's what my LG P880 presents:

- `1004:61c5` when in charge-only normal mode
- `1004:631c` with MTP enabled
- `1004:631e` with PTP
- `1004:61f1` using the "LG Software protocol" (to connect with their PC counterpart, which is Windows only)
- `1004:61fe` when in tethering mode

Easy to guess: the `1004` remains the same (it's the "manufacturer ID"). But the number behind the colon changes – so the device presents itself with different "product IDs".

However, this should not reflect on the "Serial" – as the device serial in all those 5 cases is taken from the same place (`build.prop` of the system running in "normal mode"), which is bound to the *currently running ROM.* Now what happens if you switch to "fastboot mode"? That's not related to the running OS at all (put in "easy terms", you could compare this with a PC's "BIOS" or, more correctly, the "Grub" bootloader). So `fastboot` doesn't know about the ROM's serial number, and thus uses its own. With [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) it's somehow similar – in our comparison, you chose a different entry in Grub and thus booted a different system.

---

<sup>**1:** in fact, all devices I've tried, so I don't know of any exception – though with the amount of different devices available, I cannot guarantee there is no exception at all</sup>

Comment: That's what I was particular with. I was wondering why the device's serial aren't identical when I am at `adb` and when I am at `fastboot`.

Comment: Now, when go to fastboot mode (using Linux terminal). The device just shows `> FASTBOOT mode ...`. No other information on display. When I execute `sudo fastboot oem unlock`. The terminal just show ellipses

Comment: Well, @Ephramar, that's a different issue for a separate question. At SE, we have the policy of [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154) :)

Comment: Haha. Sorry. I honestly haven't read about that. I'll be accepting this one as an answer. Thanks for the help :)